# A database of all combinations of 39 numbers taken 5 at a time, total combinations = 575757

Tags: query, number-table

I want to create a numerical database of all combinations of 39 integers(1 Through 39) taken 5 at a time. I know the total possible combinations = 575757. This would be the size of the database.

I would then like to query the database for various criteria, e.g. number of combinations that are made up of all even numbers, all odd numbers, 1 even, 1 odd, 2 even, 2 odd, etc,  and then query those results for other criteria such as restricted sums of all integers, and range distribution.

How would I do this? Obviously this is a Lottery oriented idea and I expect nothing but ridicule and disdain.

Answer (score 4):

Ridicule and disdain aside, the following query would return all possible permutations of your integers.

```
SELECT n1.i, n2.i, n3.i, n4.i, n5.i
FROM numbers AS n1
INNER JOIN numbers AS n2 ON n1.i<n2.i
INNER JOIN numbers AS n3 ON n2.i<n3.i
INNER JOIN numbers AS n4 ON n3.i<n4.i
INNER JOIN numbers AS n5 ON n4.i<n5.i
```

.. given that the table or common table expression `numbers` contains 39 unique records with `1<=i<=39`.

You could add different filters for your purposes, like how many odd numbers:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN n1.i%2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
      (CASE WHEN n2.i%2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
      (CASE WHEN n3.i%2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
      (CASE WHEN n4.i%2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
      (CASE WHEN n5.i%2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>howmanyoddnums
```

.. or even numbers (`WHEN nx.i%2=0 THEN ...`). And because the numbers are "ordered" with the `<` in the join, `n1.i` will always be the lowest and `n5.i` the highest.

Any more advanced features (or tuning for that matter) will come down to what platform and dialect of SQL you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the query @Daniel supplied](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/76146/3684) to get combinations *without repetitions*.
In Postgres, you can use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to generate the base table on the fly (typically faster than using a table of numbers).
In other databases, you would create a table with *one* column, fill it with sequential numbers and base the query on it instead.

```
WITH t(a) AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series (1,6))
SELECT t1.a AS a1
     , t2.a AS a2
     , t3.a AS a3
     , t4.a AS a4
     , t5.a AS a5
FROM   t AS t1
JOIN   t AS t2 ON t2.a < t1.a
JOIN   t AS t3 ON t3.a < t2.a
JOIN   t AS t4 ON t4.a < t3.a
JOIN   t AS t5 ON t5.a < t4.a
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3326)

Basic problems like you describe are probably best solved with [combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).  You need the [binomial coefficient ("from n choose k")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Number of rows with all odd numbers (there are 19):

```
select (19!) / ((14!) * (5!)) = 11628
```

Number of rows with all even numbers:

```
select (20!) / ((15!) * (5!)) = 15504
```

1 event, 4 odd:

```
select 19 * ((20!) / ((16!) * (4!))) = 92055
```

Etc.
But I guess a table can be useful to play with conditions and verify results.